# GridViewDataComboBoxColumn distance between combobox and values

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a DevExpress Grid View control (ASP.Net), and one of my columns is a GridViewDataComboBoxColumn. The datasource for the dropdown is set in the code behind and there are no issues there. The only problem I seem to be having is that there is a large distance between the combobox and the values when you click the drop down.

[image: big distance]

Any idea what I've done wrong here?

```
  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="Grid" runat="server" KeyFieldName="CompetencyEmployeeLevelLinkId" EnableRowsCache="False" ClientInstanceName="grid" Width="100%" OnCellEditorInitialize="EditingCell"
                    OnCustomJSProperties="Grid_CustomJSProperties" OnBatchUpdate="OnBatchUpdate" OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdate" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableTheming="True" Theme="PlasticBlue">
                    <SettingsEditing Mode="Batch">
                        <BatchEditSettings EditMode="Cell" StartEditAction="Click"></BatchEditSettings>
                    </SettingsEditing>
                    <SettingsBehavior ColumnResizeMode="Control"></SettingsBehavior>
                    <ClientSideEvents BatchEditStartEditing="OnBatchStartEdit" />
                    <Columns>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Competency">
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PreviousAScore" Caption="Previous A Score">
                            <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="PreviousBScore" Caption="Previous B Score">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="MentorA" Caption="Mentor's A Score">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn FieldName="MentorB" Caption="Mentor's B Score">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                            <PropertiesComboBox />
                        </dx:GridViewDataComboBoxColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Description" Caption="Development Plan">
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="RequiredScore" Caption="Required Score">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                        <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Achieved" Caption="Achieved">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                            <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                            <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                    </Columns>
                    <SettingsEditing Mode="Batch" />
                    <Settings VerticalScrollableHeight="400" VerticalScrollBarMode="Visible" VerticalScrollBarStyle="Virtual" />
                    <SettingsPager>
                        <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="False" />
                    </SettingsPager>
                </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: What are you doing in the EditingCell event handler? What CSS styles do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with a CSS class that I had in a parent container. The problematic element was the "Display: inline" property:

```
#container
```

{
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 80px;
}

Removing this solved the problem. Not sure that I understand why this was the problem though but at least the issue is solved. Hope this helps someone else sometime.